# I dont uderstand math result 1+2*3*+4*5 = 121

Tags: javascript, c#

I use this code from C#

```
  public double CalculateExpression()
    {
        double result = -1;

        var javascriptLangualeType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));
        dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(javascriptLangualeType, false);
        obj.Language = "javascript";

        try
        {
            result = obj.Eval(Expression);
            Result = result.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Result = "ERROR";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When i want to Evaluate this expression (inside is '*' and '+' ):

```
var expresion = "1+2*3*+4*5";
```

I expected i get exception r any other kind of error but result of this is 121. Can someone tell me why is this expression recognized as valid ?

I tried this expression in C# scripting and also i got result 121.

Thank you.

Comment: unary plus is just like an inverse unary minus

Comment: While this expression is actually valid for many languages you are asking about JavaScript where almost anything is valid - see famous [Javascript WAT talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's doing this:

```
1 + (2 * 3 * (+4) * 5)
```

Which is clearer with a minus since we don't typically use `+4` to denote `4`:

```
1+2*3*-4*5
```

Expands to

```
1 + (2 * 3 * (-4) * 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Right To Left with * taking precedence over +.

So  (1) + (2*(3*(+(4*5)))) = 121

It helps to read it right to left.
Also the + sign is treated as +20   or "20"   It is not an operator but a positive/negative sign on the value (4*5)

Comment: Just wrong :) - unary operators have higher precedence in almost all languages - and definitely in JavaScript.

Comment: I would expect the evaluation to Keep going Left of the + and see the * which would  cause the * to "win" which forces the + sign to become a unary against the (4*5)   so (+(4*5)) or (+20)  which is multiplied by the 3.     This is why I Never Ever rely on order of precedence in anything I do ever.  I do not trust any runtimes ever as I could be wrong or miss an  exponent or something similar.